# match multiple date formats with logstash date filter plugin

Tags: logstash

I have a date in my logs like below formats,

```
YYYY-M-dd and YYYY-MM-d and YYYY-M-d

2020-9-21
2020-11-1
2020-9-1
```

date filter plugin match with

```
date {
    match => [ "event_date" ,"yyyy-MM-dd"]
}
```

Some logs I get date parse exception because of this. Is it possible to match all of these. I means match this format if not match another date format.

The error is

```
"failed to parse field [event_date] of type [date] in document with id '...'. Preview of field's value: '2017-11-2'", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse date field [2017-11-2] with format [strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis]", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"date_time_parse_exception", "reason"=>"date_time_parse_exception: Failed to parse with all enclosed parsers"}}}}}}
```

How can i solve it ? Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried first answer but didn't solve my issue. @YLR's way also good way to improve.
I have solved my question with changing fields like M to MM with if conditions. Below is an example.

```
if [monthday] == "1"{
    mutate {
        update => { "monthday" => "01" }
    }
}else if [monthday] == "2"{
    mutate {
        update => { "monthday" => "02" }
    }
}else if [monthday] == "3"{
    mutate {
        update => { "monthday" => "03" }
    }
}
....
```

That solved my question but its little bit hard way.

Answer (score 1):

One of a solution is to have a mechanism like a switch implemented by the date filter with the tag_on_failure value. It looks like this :

```
filter{
    date {
        match => [ "event_date" ,"yyyy-MM-dd"]
        tag_on_failure => [ "not_format_date1"]
    }
    if "not_format_date1" in [tags] {
        date {
            match => [ "event_date" ,"yyyy-MM-d"]
            tag_on_failure => [ "not_format_date2"]
        }
    }
    if "not_format_date2" in [tags] {
        date {
            match => [ "event_date" ,"yyyy-M-d"]
            tag_on_failure => [ "no_format"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering but you have syntax error. as tags => [tags], and if ... { date { match {.. . I have replaced syntax. But  didnt worked

Comment: "failed to parse field [event_Date] of type [date] in document with id '...'. Preview of field's value: '2017-11-2'", 
 "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse date field [2017-11-2] with format [strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis]",
 "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"date_time_parse_exception", "reason"=>"date_time_parse_exception: Failed to parse with all enclosed parsers"}}}}}}

Comment: Sorry my mistake, juste change tags with [tags] in if condition, I've edited my answer

Comment: There was still syntax error. I have edited your answer but still having same issue as my second comment